# Digitally signed executable being blocked when downloaded in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, exe, code-signing

I am trying to distribute an installer that both the contents and the actual setup.exe file have been digitally signed.

When downloading via Internet Explorer (and possibly other browsers), the file is "blocked"

i.e.

[image: Blocked file]

and it throws up the unknown publisher dialog, despite it actually having a valid digital signature.

[image: Unknown publisher :(]

If I manually copy the file across from the network or unblock it, it works fine.

I have tried using the Sysinternals Streams file and the instructions on [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2009/03/14/understanding-the-internet-file-blocking-and-unblocking.aspx) but my file does not seem to contain any Zones, so can't understand the cause.

FYI. Everything is created and signed on a **Windows 7** machine and then uploaded to a **Windows 2008 R2 Server** and then I am downloading the file via **Internet Explorer 6 in Windows XP SP3**.

Any idea's? I need to distribute the file to a market that has little or no knowledge of the internet or computer security, so a dialog such as below would be scary. If there was a way to change it so it would display our digitally signed certificate (i.e. our company name in the publisher) then this could be a suitable work around.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Eric Lawrence has an excellent post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/22/authenticode-code-signing-for-developers-for-file-downloads-building-smartscreen-application-reputation.aspx) about authenticode signing, it's likely that the answer to your question can be found there.

Comment: Hi Larry, I had signed my files using the Sign tool, but just in case, this time I have used signtool.exe with the signwizard argument and went through it that way. I am currently testing now. Thanks ;)

Comment: Btw, I don't believe that signing will get you past the "blocked" - that's what's called the "mark of the web" and is intended to put up a prompt on all downloaded content.  What signing does is to change the scary "This software could not be verified" dialog into a friendlier "This software came from Gavin" dialog.

Comment: Hi Larry, I think I'm at the limit of what I can do to be honest. I am using a self signed certificate using the makecert and signtool applications provided by the MS SDK. Up until this point, it was fine, but because the Root CA is not on the machine, it can't verify the chain and still shows "Unknown publisher". Once you have unblocked or clicked Run, any further dialogs like this show the company name correctly. Looks like to continue, I need to purchase a valid certificate from Verisign etc. Thanks again ;)

Comment: I believe that's right - Windows requires that you have a valid code signing certificate which chains to a valid root certificate.  I believe that Eric calls this out in his blog post.